# why when I printk a physical address with %pa or %pap I get a warning

Tags: linux, gcc, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver

In my code I'm doing the following

```
virtAddr = kmalloc(<some size>, GFP_KERNEL);
physAddr = virt_to_phys(virtAddr);

printk(MODULE_NAME "physAddr = %pap\n", physAddr);
printk(MODULE_NAME "physAddr = %pa\n", physAddr);
```

When I compile the code I get a following warning:

`warning: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void *’, but argument 2 has type ‘phys_addr_t’ [-Wformat]`

[Documentation for printk formats](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/printk-formats.txt)  says that I must use `%pa[p]`. So why I'm getting this warning?

Here is my output of `gcc --version`

`gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.`

Comment: @nephtes `[p]` means it is optional. In other words I can either use `%pap` or `%pa`. if use `%pa[p]` it prints out `[p]` at the end of the output.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that was dumb, I guess I was too slow to delete that comment.  Anyways: the key point in the documentation you linked is "passed by reference".  Try passing &physAddr (the address of the object)

Comment: @nephtes That worked. Thanks!